# Is it important to specify the position:absolute of an image inside an absolutely positioned div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Recently our main website underwent a redesign wrt UI - New Navigation/Footer etc.
The Main Website(with it's own UI - Navigation/Footer etc) hosts other html pages which are called in the main Page.

Prior to the redesign, whenever we created html pages( for Sliders/Hover Effects etc) with 
-Relatively Positioned Main Div (Main Container - Relative)
           -having Absolutely Positioned Div  (Inner Container - Absolute)
                  -which had Images inside it  (Image - Content)

We never had to specify - position absolute for the Images/Contents of the Absolutely Positioned Inner Container.
They all behaved like the Inner Container which was absolutely positioned.

But in the New UI - it's become necessary to define the position of the contents.

Is this abnormal?

I believe this is an aberration of sorts - something wrong with the New UI. Is it being caused by the CSS of the Main Page?
Please share if you have encountered something like this.

Comment: Anything inside an absolutely positioned element will move along with it, and shouldn't need to be positioned absolutely itself. In fact if the image inside is also absolutely positioned, then the image and it's container will be independent of each other. That said, we can't help you fix the issue without code. Please post your HTML structure and CSS styling.

Comment: I was incorrect. Positioning a parent absolutely will act the same as positioning it relatively, in terms of how it affects the child's placement. They will NOT be independent. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/DUEzd/

Comment: Thank you so much for describing the same. So it IS important to specifically mention the position of the content elements. Am i right?

Comment: It really shouldn't be, unless you need to move then in relation to their parents which are already moved. I have never once run into the need to absolutely position inside an absolutely positioned. If you'd like to post a Fiddle with a dumbed down example, or some code, we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the `<html>` element is absolutely positioned to `0,0`. Then all content is relatively positioned to that, unless you use CSS to absolutely assign position to an element.

So, if you have a `<div>` that's absolutely positioned to `top:10; left:10`, then it is placed 10 pixels from the left of and 10 pixels down from the content box of the `<html>` element. All content placed in this `div` is relatively positioned to the `div`'s position (e.g. `10,10`). If you need to absolutely position an element within the `<div>`, then you will need to specify CSS to absolutely position it, say `top:10; left:10`. The absolute coordinates would be `top:20, left:20` from, say, the `<html>` element's position. It's position within the `<div>` would be `top:10; left:10`, as specified by the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it is necessary to specify the position of the content inside the container div?

Comment: @hello_world Only if you want to absolutely position it to someplace within that element (e.g. if you don't want the element to follow the normal document flow).